# Displaying PDF to user

Tags: security, forms, pdf

We're providing a web form whereby users fill in their personal information; some of it is sensitive information (SSN, Birthday, etc).  Upon user submission, the data is prefilled into a PDF which is then made available via a link.

We are creating the PDF in a folder that has write access on the website.

How can we safely create and add PDFs in this folder, with whatever naming scheme (use a GUID?), such that another user cannot guess/spoof the PDF file location, type this in the URL and access another person's PDF?

Maybe the PDF folder has rights only specific to the user, but that may be a different question on how that is accomplished.  (The number of users is unknown, as this will be open to public).

Any thoughts on this?  In a nut shell, we need to allow the user to view a PDF of the data they just entered while preventing more-savvy users to figure out the location of PDF files, allowing access to other files.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

trying to obfuscate the path to a file isn't really making it secure.  I would find a way to email or another way to fetch it for the user instead of allowing access to an open directory.

Make the web app fetch the file for the user instead of relying on web server open folder permissions.

just keep in mind obfuscation isn't really security.

Answer (score 0):

If it's really just for the moment, create a completely random file (`20384058532045850.pdf`) in a temporary directory, serve that to the user immediately and remove it after a certain period of time.

Whether your web app has write rights on that directory or not (I assume you are talking about `chmod` user rights) is not important, it can't be breached trough the web server and I don't see a problem in revealing the directory path per se - you have to reveal something in giving the user a URL to download. If your PDF names are random enough, there is practically no risk of somebody being able to guess the name of another PDF file in the same directory.

As the PDF contains sensitive data: Don't forget to turn off caching to prevent a local copy of the PDF being saved on the client's browser cache.

I don't know for sure whether turning off caching through the appropriate headers is enough to prevent local caching in all browsers. You might have to look into that.

Answer (score 0):

For the purpose of pdf's, would it not be better (*I know I will get flamed for this*) to store the actual pdf into the database as a BLOB, which would be on the back-end of the website in question?

There will be no reference to the URL anywhere nor will there be a specific path highlighted in any links on that form.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to proxy the file through your application (fpassthru() in php for example), this allows you to use what ever access control/identification system you already use for the dynamic content.

If you don't have any means of identifying your users and restricting access, and assuming your platform has a secure session mechanism, you can protect the file by storing the filename in the user's session and then returning that file (and only that file) to the user when requested.  This should mean that an attacker would have to spoof a session to access the file so this should be as secure as your session mechanism is.